# NavigationLink not working properly(SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

My intention is to move to the next screen once I click the log in button or the get started button. If I click on them currently it just displays the view in a smaller window while leaving the background image on screen. I am fairly new to coding so I'm sure its a simple mistake but any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I currently have:

```
struct StartingPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Blackhair")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 510, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        }
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Welcome to")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title)
                    .background()
                    .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
                Text("Redacted")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("600"))
                    .font(.title)
                    .background()
                
            }
            Text("A safe & relaxing place after a day of work")
                .font(.title2)
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
            HStack {
                FirstButton(text: "Log In")
                SecondButton(text: "Get Started")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my buttons are setup like this:

```
struct FirstButton: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: LogInScreen(), label: {
                Text(text)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("600"))
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .border(Color("600"))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle)
                    .padding()
            })
        }
    }
}//End of struct
```

Comment: Put the navigation view at the highest point in your app. Usually the content view

Comment: awesome! Thank you! I'm going to give it a shot to see if it works